# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

Tags: pantheon-files

I'm on Freya 0.3.1 64bit and get the message

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
```

when running an electron shell app.

I tried to start it with

```
GTK_MODULES=pantheon-filechooser-module electron .
```

and tried to set

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings enabled-gtk-modules "['pantheon-filechooser-module']"
```

but neither worked.

Any chance to enable that module?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to use the file chooser module with non-gtk3 apps. You will always see this warning message with those apps. When the module fails to load, you'll get the fallback gtk2 chooser.

Comment: so its expected behaviour?

Comment: @FerriSutanto that's correct

Comment: GTK_MODULES=pantheon-filechooser-module  can be made to work in current eOS though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove space in 'Screenshot Monitor.exe', for example

```
sudo cp /usr/share/ssm/Screenshot\ Monitor.exe /usr/share/ssm/sm.exe
```

and then change `/usr/share/applications/Screenshot\ Monitor.desktop` to

```
Exec=mono '/usr/share/ssm/sm.exe'
```