# Screenshot Monitor doesn't start

Tags: release-juno, thirdpartyapps

I need this program for my work and I installed it with gdebi. I can see the icon but I can't get it to start. The icon goes up and down when I click on it but nothing opens. How can I get it to work? What should I provide you with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue.  I am able to start the program from the command line:

```
mono /usr/share/ssm/Screenshot\ Monitor.exe
```

This will work as well:

```
mono '/usr/share/ssm/Screenshot Monitor.exe'
```

A Log In window appeared.

[image]

But I'm not sure why it won't start by clicking on the icon.

I installed it in Ubuntu and it works just fine. You can launch it from the icon. I didn't notice any differences in the respective **.desktop** files in Ubuntu and elementary OS.

Regarding the message `"Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"`:

There is an answer to that here:
[Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-pantheon-filechooser-module)

Comment: Thanks for your swift response! So, I was using Kali and win10 and I had no problem with them. Then, I wanted to try out elementaryOS because it looks just beautiful. However, as I mentioned I couldn't get the program to work so I had to install plank on ubuntu to have almost the same feeling but I really want to go back to elementaryOS. I'll install it alongside ubuntu and if it works, I'll be happy as a child)

Comment: I haven't tried on elementary OS Juno. I only tried it on elementary OS Loki since that is the tag you used.  Yes, elementary OS is a beautiful operating system, and it looks like Screenshot Monitor still works if you don't mind running it from the command line.  But I can see how that would get old after a while if you use it a lot.

Comment: Their support's response is:
Hello,
Please try to start application with terminal command: mono '/usr/share/ssm/Screenshot Monitor.exe'
Thank you. 
Just as you said, it seems that there is no way around this issue. I appreciate your responses. Have a great day!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.  What I find strange is that the command you enter in the terminal is exactly the same as the `Exec=` statement in the **.desktop** file.  It seems to me it should start by clicking the icon. Weird.

Comment: Sometimes code is art more than code 